# Как правильно использовать индексы для таблицы с геолокациями

Tags: sql, база-данных, индексы

У меня есть таблица с геолокациями, соответственно у каждой записи помимо всего есть широта и долгота.
Индексы применяются у меня пока что только для id, а я хочу оптимизировать свой запрос, который находит по входным широте и долготе ближайшую геолокацию.
Выглядит он так

```
SELECT marker.id,, `lat`, `lng`, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lng` ) - radians(".$long.") ) + sin( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM marker
         JOIN image ON image.marker_id = marker.id
         GROUP BY marker.id
         ORDER BY distance LIMIT 3
```

С индексами только начал работать и не могу сообразить, как тут их максимально эффективно применить и помогут ли они вообще в этой задаче? Я в принципе готов пожертвовать дисковым пространством для увеличения скорости этого запроса. В общем, подскажите какой вид индексов использовать, для каких столбцов? Уместно ли это тут вообще? Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Индексы могут помочь в первичной фильтрации исходной выборки. Вы можете добавить парный индекс по целым координатам (ширине и долготе), либо два индекса отдельно, и проверять расстояние только среди тех локаций, что подходят для данной пары целых чисел, или для соседних позиций.
Если не использовать индекс, то при большом объеме данных будет довольно долгая сортировка и лишние рассчеты дистанции.
Наверно, проще сделать два отдельных индекса, т.к. у вас лимит дистанции равен трём.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что мне достаточно сделать индексы для этих двух полей и SQL уже всё сам разрулит, и запрос получит хороший буст в скорости? Или мне как то будет надо основываясь на этом изменении ещё и запрос менять?

Comment: Нет. Тебе нужно а) добавить два целочисленных столбца б) создать по ним индексы в) в поисковом выражении сначала выбрать только те координаты, которые в теории могут подойти: select latInt, longInt from location where latInt between x-3 and x+3 and longInt between y-3 and y+3. Это будет первичной фильтрацией: вместо поиска по квадрату 360*360 вариантов нужно будет искать по квадрату 7*7. Это должно серьезно сэкономить время, но лучше дополнительно сделать замер времени на реальном наборе данных. А дальше примерно то же, что и раньше.

Comment: В теории, скорость может увеличиться до 3000 раз (360*360/7*7), хотя тут логично использовать время сортировки -- n*log(n). На практике, скорее всего, будет заметно скромнее (из-за разной плотности), но дополнительный прирост тут можно ожидать за счет размещения данных в кэше или в оперативной памяти (более крупный блок может не уместиться целиком).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я правильно понял идею: мы заводим два столбца, в них храним очень округлённо координаты(без цифр после запятой), заводим на них индекс, и прежде чем считать вот эту вот сложную дистанцию - мы сужаем выборку?

Comment: да, идея такая. Но не забудьте сделать сравнение скорости выполнения на реальных данных. И помните, что оптимизация не должна быть преждевременной. Если скорость проседает в этом месте -- надо добавить индекс, иначе, можно не добавлять.

Comment: Хотя, вам же нужны только первые три совпадения, а не дистанция в 3. Тут я ступил, но идея прежняя. Не обязательно использовать целочисленный индекс: можно хранить, скажем, одну цифру после запятой -- поэксперементируйте на реальных данных. Если запрос не вернет ответов, можно будет послать ещё один с увеличением площади

Comment: Понял, буду пробовать, спасибо

Comment: Вы не указали какая у вас БД. Многие базы данных поддерживают работу с гео-данными. Если вы используюте одну из таких БД то есть смысл воспользоваться специальными типами данных - “spatial”. Это может ускорить расчёты по формуле “haversine” во много раз.